# Unable to set resize behaviour of textarea in ui services

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to change the resize style attribute of a textarea but it results in a runtime error: "Invalid argument: none"

```
app.createTextArea().setName("test").setStyleAttribute("resize", "none");
```

Shouldn't the resize CSS property be supported for textarea's?

Answer (score 0):

Not all CSS is supported, you want to use HTMLService for full HTML but.....
You could do this:

```
  app.createTextArea().setSize(width, height)
```

With kind regards,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: Or also [setPixelSize(width, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textarea#setPixelSize) (integer values)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I tried to use setSize on the textarea but this doesn't prevent the user from resizing the widget in the ui. Using "resize: none" in css makes the resize handle disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
    max-width: 100px; 
    max-height: 100px;
}
```